# Dificuldade extrema em gerar PDF com PHP ou JavaScript

Tags: php, mpdf, jspdf

Dificuldade extrema em gerar PDF com PHP ou JavaScript

Estou aqui na **tentativa** de **gerar arquivo PDF** pelo **HTML**.

Fiz 3 **tentativas**.

O **HTML** e o **CSS** são os **mesmos** para as **3 tentativas**.

**Tentativa 1 -> PHP => Usando mPDF com CSS em uma variável PHP**

```
<?php

  $css = "
        img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
        div.relatorio {
            width: 95%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        div.relatorio ul.border {
            border: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
            background-color: black;
        }
        div.relatorio .centralizado {
            text-align: center !important;
        }
        div.relatorio .backCinza {
            background-color: rgb(217,217,217);
        }
        div.relatorio ul.ulInlineBlock li {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        div.relatorio ul.lancamento li, div.relatorio ul.resumo li {
            height: 100%;
            line-height: 18px;
            font-size: .85em;
            border-left: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        div.relatorio ul.lancamento li {
            width: 113.5px !important;
        }
        div.relatorio ul.resumo li {
            width: 150px !important;
        }
        div.relatorio ul.lancamento li:first-child, div.relatorio ul.resumo li:first-child {
            border-left: none;
        }
        .erro, .hCentralizadoAvisos {
            color: rgb(255,0,0);
        }
        .hCentralizado, .hCentralizadoAvisos, .erro {
            width: auto;
            line-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .labelPequeno {
            width: 150px;
            height: 30px;
            padding: 3px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        span.vertical {
            -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
            -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
            writing-mode: vertical-lr;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        span.comum {
        }
        div.cabecalhoVertical {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 800px;
            height: 220px;
            border: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
        }
        div.cabecalhoVertical div {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            border-right: .1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        div.cabecalhoVertical div span {
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
  ";

  $html = " 
    <div class='relatorio'> 
        <img src='http://www.wesleyanagceu.com.br/_imgs/gceu.png' /> <h1>Relatório Mensal</h1>  
        <br><br>        
        <div class='cabecalhoVertical'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Nome do Gcéu</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='vertical'>Supervisor</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Líder</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve Supervisão</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Jejum</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Evangelismo</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Membros Compromissados</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Visitantes</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Crianças de 0 à 12 anos</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Total de presentes</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Ofertas</span></div>                   
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Disicpulados</span></div>                  
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Número de decisões</span></div>                    
        </div>  
        <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Célula 1</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Cleonice</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jonas</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>50</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>10</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>13</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>73</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>22,65</span></div>                    
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>2</span></div>                    
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>11</span></div>
        </div>           
        <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Celula 2</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jonas</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>10</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>5</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>3</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>18</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>78,39</span></div>                    
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>3</span></div>                    
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>1</span></div>
        </div>           
        <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Celula TOP</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
            <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
        </div>           
        <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jesuita</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Josefina Etelvina</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Josefina Etelvina</span></div>
            <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
        </div>           
        <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Tassito</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
            <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>";

    require_once "../_scripts/_php/_configuracoes/erros.php";
    require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

    $pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['debug' => true]);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->charset_in = "UTF-8";
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->WriteHTML( $css, 1 );
    $pdf->WriteHTML( $html );
    $pdf->Output("relatorio.pdf","D");

?>
```

**Tentativa 2 -> PHP => Usando mPDF com inclusão de CSS**

```
<?php

  $css = file_get_contents('../_scripts/_css/relatorio.css'); // external css

  $html = " 
    <div class='relatorio'> 
        <img src='http://www.wesleyanagceu.com.br/_imgs/gceu.png' /> <h1>Relatório Mensal</h1>  
        <br><br>        
        <div class='cabecalhoVertical'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Nome do Gcéu</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='vertical'>Supervisor</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Líder</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve Supervisão</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Jejum</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Evangelismo</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Membros Compromissados</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Visitantes</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Crianças de 0 à 12 anos</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Total de presentes</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Ofertas</span></div>                   
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Disicpulados</span></div>                  
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Número de decisões</span></div>                    
        </div>  
        <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Célula 1</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Cleonice</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jonas</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>50</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>10</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>13</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>73</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>22,65</span></div>                    
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>2</span></div>                    
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>11</span></div>
        </div>           
        <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Celula 2</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jonas</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>10</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>5</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>3</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>18</span></div>
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>78,39</span></div>                    
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>3</span></div>                    
            <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>1</span></div>
        </div>           
        <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Celula TOP</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
            <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
        </div>           
        <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jesuita</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Josefina Etelvina</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Josefina Etelvina</span></div>
            <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
        </div>           
        <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Tassito</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
            <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
            <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>";

    require_once "../_scripts/_php/_configuracoes/erros.php";
    require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

    $pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['debug' => true]);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->charset_in = "UTF-8";
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->WriteHTML( $css, 1 );
    $pdf->WriteHTML( $html );
    $pdf->Output("relatorio.pdf","D");

?>
```

**Tentativa 3 -> JavaScipt => Usando JSPDF e canvas2image**

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.createPdf = function(parametros) {
        
        var config = {              
            'fileName':'html-to-pdf'
        };
        
        if (parametros){
            $.extend(config, parametros);
        }                            

        var quotes = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));

        html2canvas(quotes, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

                for (var i = 0; i <= quotes.clientHeight/980; i++) {
                    var srcImg  = canvas;
                    var sX      = 0;
                    var sY      = 980*i;
                    var sWidth  = 900;
                    var sHeight = 980;
                    var dX      = 0;
                    var dY      = 0;
                    var dWidth  = 900;
                    var dHeight = 980;

                    window.onePageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    onePageCanvas.setAttribute('width', 900);
                    onePageCanvas.setAttribute('height', 980);
                    var ctx = onePageCanvas.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.drawImage(srcImg,sX,sY,sWidth,sHeight,dX,dY,dWidth,dHeight);

                    var canvasDataURL = onePageCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
                    var width         = onePageCanvas.width;
                    var height        = onePageCanvas.clientHeight;

                    if (i > 0) {
                        pdf.addPage(612, 791);
                    }

                    pdf.setPage(i+1);
                    pdf.addImage(canvasDataURL, 'PNG', 20, 40, (width*.62), (height*.62));
                }

                pdf.save(config.fileName);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
 

function createPDF() {
    $('#relatorioPDF').createPdf({
        'fileName' : 'testePDF'
    });
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
div.relatorio {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.relatorio ul.border {
    border: 1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
 background-color: black;
}
div.relatorio .centralizado {
    text-align: center !important;
}
div.relatorio .backCinza {
    background-color: rgb(217,217,217);
}
div.relatorio ul.ulInlineBlock li {
    display: inline-block;
}
div.relatorio ul.lancamento li, div.relatorio ul.resumo li {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: .85em;
    border-left: 1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div.relatorio ul.lancamento li {
    width: 113.5px !important;
}
div.relatorio ul.resumo li {
    width: 150px !important;
}
div.relatorio ul.lancamento li:first-child, div.relatorio ul.resumo li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
.erro, .hCentralizadoAvisos {
    color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
.hCentralizado, .hCentralizadoAvisos, .erro {
    width: auto;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.labelPequeno {
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
span.vertical {
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
span.comum {
}
div.cabecalhoVertical {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 220px;
    border: 1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
}
div.cabecalhoVertical div {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    border-right: 1px rgb(0,0,0) solid;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
div.cabecalhoVertical div span {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>

<div class='relatorio' id='relatorioPDF'> 
 <img src='http://www.wesleyanagceu.com.br/_imgs/gceu.png' /> <h1>Relatório Mensal</h1> 
 <br><br>  
 <div class='cabecalhoVertical'>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Nome do Gcéu</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='vertical'>Supervisor</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'   >Líder</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve Supervisão</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Jejum</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Houve dia de Evangelismo</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Membros Compromissados</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Visitantes</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Crianças de 0 à 12 anos</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Total de presentes</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Ofertas</span></div>     
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Disicpulados</span></div>     
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='vertical'>Número de decisões</span></div>     
 </div> 
 <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Célula 1</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Cleonice</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jonas</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>50</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>10</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>13</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>73</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>22,65</span></div>     
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>2</span></div>     
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>11</span></div>
 </div>    
 <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Celula 2</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jonas</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>Não</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>10</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>5</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>3</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>18</span></div>
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>78,39</span></div>     
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>3</span></div>     
  <div style='width:050px;'><span class='comum'>1</span></div>
 </div>    
 <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Celula TOP</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
  <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
 </div>    
 <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Jesuita</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Josefina Etelvina</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Josefina Etelvina</span></div>
  <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
 </div>    
 <div class='border cabecalhoVertical' style='backgroud-color:none; height: 50px !important;'>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Tassito</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
  <div style='width:100px;'><span class='comum'>Carlos</span></div>
  <div style='width:500px;'><span class='comum'>Não houve Reuniões para esse Gcéu</span></div>
 </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="createPDF();">pdf</button>
```

**Resultados:**

**Como deveria ser : **
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**As tentativas 1 e 2 mostram o pdf como abaixo :** Css não funciona
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Tentativa 3 :** Parte do Css não funciona
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O que pode ser feito para resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Eu usei uma vez a biblioteca [PHPSpreadSheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) (antiga PHPExcel). Eu montava a tabela em excel (o que eu achei bem mais fácil) e no final só converto para PDF:

```
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Mpdf($spreadsheet);
$writer->save("relatorio.pdf");
```

Da uma olhada na documentação e ve se atende ao que precisa. Mas ela é bem completa, pode colocar imagem, html, juntar colunas, linhas.

Comment: instalei vi composer para testar mas não estou encontrando na documentação adicionar CSS ao HTML que vai ser raenderizado para PHP. voc por acaso não teria um exemplo?

Comment: É mas parece que é apenas para Excell que ele esporta

Comment: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#pdf

Comment: Sim. Mas parece que todos precisam da variável $spreadsheet. Isso quer dizer que terei que criar um .xls antes de converter para .pdf usando por exemplo mPDF? Isso não seria fazer 2 tabalhos? Não entendi muito bem.